# Can I write $[a,a)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

I have a set of real numbers defined within the interval $[a,b]$. I have defined a variable $x$ that is supposed to divide the real number space into $[a,x)$ and $(x,b]$. I would also like to include the null sets on both the extremes.

Comment: $\{x\}$ is not $[x,x)$, it can be $[x,x]$ though.

Answer (score 2):

By definition $$[a,a) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : a \leq x < a\} = \varnothing$$ and similar for $(a,a]$. So the answer to your question would be yes.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.
[a, a)
does not contain any points
because any point x in it
must satisfy
$a \le x < a$
which is a contradiction.